# System_profiler OSX Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, system-profiler

I am Looking to retrieve some dataTypes from System_profeiler ,programatically from Objective-c cocoa app ,

Can Some1 advice me How can I do so ? In C/Obj-C ?

All I have found that it is a command tool,but can I get its output to my app ?

A simple example Would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Using system_profiler along with its `-xml` option should make it pretty easy to pass its output to `NSXMLDocument` with `initWithXMLString`.

Comment: I agree with @vcsjones.  Using `NSTask`, I believe you are notified when the command has finished via a delegate.  Else use `posix_spawn()` and trap `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: @trojanfoe So there is no direct access ?I have to run it in cmd and save to XML file and then to open the file ?

Comment: You don't have to save the file to disk - you can capture it with stdout as @trojanfoe described. In the case of NSTask, you can receive stdout to an NSPipe. I don't think there is a "direct" API for what system_profiler is doing. Sure, the APIs it uses are there, but that's probably a lot more work to figure them all out.

Comment: @vcsjones Wow everything here is Hard work (sorry 2 weeks only on mac) , make an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @vcsjones actually I don't want them all 
I need only 2 dataTypes memory and graphics, maybe it will be actually easier to figure them out "directly" ?